# About base64.b64encode() and b64decode()

Tags: python, base64

Just like when I encode the int16 array by :
base64.standard_b64encode(item)
where the item is :

```
[-32167  25610 -18240  -4487 -14285   2804  17597 -24949 -12195  13875] <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

then I get the result as :

```
b'WYIKZMC4ee4zyPQKvUSLnl3QMzY=' <class 'bytes'>
```

then do an inverse process:

```
base64.standard_b64decode(b'WYIKZMC4ee4zyPQKvUSLnl3QMzY=')
```

the result is :

```
b'Y\x82\nd\xc0\xb8y\xee3\xc8\xf4\n\xbdD\x8b\x9e]\xd036' <class 'bytes'>
```

Why will be like this ? Why it is not the same to value of 'item' ?

Comment: Can you include a running script? Just initialize the array and to the encode / decode.

Answer (score 2):

`base64` encoding works on byte strings.  It accepts byte strings, and it produces byte strings.  When you pass your `numpy` array of 16-bit integers to b64encode, `numpy` is kind enough to convert the array into a byte string on your behalf.  When you decode it, base64 doesn't know where the data came from, so it produces a byte string.

Fortunately, you can ask `numpy` to re-import it:

```
import numpy as np
import array
data = np.array( [-32167, 25610, -18240, -4487, -14285, 2804, 17597, -24949, -12195, 13875], dtype=np.int16)

x = base64.standard_b64encode( data )
print(x)
y = base64.standard_b64decode( x )
print(len(y))
print(y)
z = np.frombuffer(y, dtype=np.int16)
print(z)
```

Output:

```
b'WYIKZMC4ee4zyPQKvUSLnl3QMzY='
20
b'Y\x82\nd\xc0\xb8y\xee3\xc8\xf4\n\xbdD\x8b\x9e]\xd036'
[-32167  25610 -18240  -4487 -14285   2804  17597 -24949 -12195  13875]
```

Comment: Yep, I noticed that just as you were typing your comment.

Comment: You can also use `struct.unpack('<10h', b'Y\x82\nd\xc0\xb8y\xee3\xc8\xf4\n\xbdD\x8b\x9e]\xd036')` (where `<` = little-endian order, `10` = length of the array, and `h` = signed 16-bit integer) to retrieve the original values (but as a `tuple` instead of the original `numpy.ndarray` type).

Comment: Yep, I started out using Python's `array` for that same purpose, but quickly realized I could have numpy do it just as easily.

Comment: How are you sure it's numpy doing the conversion and not base64?

Comment: Well, it's really neither, but I think it makes for a good mental model.  `numpy` passes an object with a "buffer" interface. `base64` hands off to `binascii` which understands the "buffer "interface.